# Is it possible to query a soap endpoint via odata?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, odata, dynamics-crm-2011

I've got a SOAP endpoint:

```
 <organization URL>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc
```

I would like to create an odata wrapper around this service, such that when navigating to `http://myodataservice/api/Entities$?filter=AccountNumber eq '123123'`

It would retrieve data from the SOAP (wsdl) service, but it would allow the client to issue odata queries.

**Is it possible to query a SOAP service using ODATA?**

Answer (score 4):

You could create an OData wrapper around a SOAP endpoint but I don't think that it is worth it.

The OData service would allow filtering, ordering and selecting by all of the properties (amongst other things) and the SOAP service may not allow all of this so your OData service would probably have to go and get all of the data and then post process it which loses the main benefit of OData in that you can do all of the filtering and sorting on the server side. You may as well just get the data client side and filter it there.

If your SOAP service somehow does have all of this support then yes, you could write an OData wrapper for it and get these benefits but it would still be a lot of work to convert all of the different possible queries into something that your SOAP service can handle.

I don't know your reasons for wanting an OData wrapper but it seems like this might be a lot of work for minimal benefit but it all depends on your use case.

Comment: thank you very much Tom, the reason i ask is because CRM 2011 exposes both soap and odata; we have been trying to query against the CSDL (odata) model, and the capabilities have been extremely limiting, please note that if we use their odata endpoint then everything works fine, however if we use the provided CSDL file as a model, then query against this model, there are many problems with serialization and it looks like its building bad linq queries

Comment: I don't think that wrapping the SOAP service will solve your problem in that case